# How to disable UIWebview horizontal scrolling?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, scroll

I've tried disabling it by inserting:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320" />
```

into my HTML string, and a dozen variations of the above in the vain hope that I just screwed up the tag syntax... but nothing seems to stop UIWebView from scrolling horizontally. And yet there are apps that manage to do this (like MobileRSS), and presumably, since they haven't gotten rejected, they're not using private APIs.

Answer (score 32):

My version, a common solution:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

[webView.scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(webView.frame.size.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)];

}
```

Comment: It is important that this code is placed in the -webViewDidFinishLoad: not somewhere else(as i did put it to viewDidLoad and was banging my head against the wall for a while)

Answer (score 8):

I eventually managed to solve this. I'd already tried setting the viewport width value, and it didn't work. What DID work was using overflow:hidden in conjunction with setting the viewport width. Thanks for answering anyhow.

Answer (score 4):

Your web page needs to have two attributes: 1 -- the viewport meta tag and 2-- a width of 320px or less, including margin and padding.

Here's a very bare HTML5 skeleton that should allow vertical scrolling and disallow horizontal scrolling, including disallowing horizontal bouncing. This also disallows zooming -- it assumes that your web page should always be shown 1-1 to the user. This is useful if you're using an UIWebView to show a user interface.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <style>
        body {width:320px;margin:0;padding:0;}
    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

if the webView content a word which has length greater than the webView. you have to break that string. so use the below code  in the div

word-wrap: break-word;

Answer (score 1):

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no initial-scale=1.0" />`

Answer (score 1):

Set the delegate for the `UIWebview`'s `UIScrollview` (on iOS5 by `webview.scrollView` and on iOS4 by traversing the subview tree and selecting the `UIScrollview` subview) to 'self' and use the following code:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y)];
}
```

Works perfectly, for some reason my HTML code was overflowing horizontally without any need for it. This fix it.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this fixes it; is more like a hack. But hey! if it does the job, who cares? (It doesn't fix it because your content is still overflowing)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.0** solution:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: webView.frame.size.width, height: webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)        
}
```