# Stopping a UIWebView from scrolling horizontally

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've a UIWebview displaying a .rtf file. The lines of text are wider than the screen.

1) Is there a way to get the text to wrap around rather than going off the edge of the screen and requiring the user to scroll.

2) Is there a way to disable horizontal scrolling in the UIWebView.

Many Thanks
Code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable UIWebview horizontal scrolling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397699/how-to-disable-uiwebview-horizontal-scrolling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the content to fit inside the view, set it's `scalesPagesToFit` property to true:

```
webView.scalesPagesToFit = YES;
```

If you do that, the pages shouldn't be horizontally scrollable. If they are, you can fiddle around with the stuff in [UIScrollView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) because UIWebView is a subclass of it.

Comment: scales to fit page, sound like it is going to shrink the content rather than wrap the text to stop it over running the sides of the screen.

Comment: It's probably the best you can do. Unless you want to strip the HTML and ad a br tag every few hundred characters the feed it back to the webview.