# How to only disable the horizontal scrolling of UIwebView from within the iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I am making a iPhone app that needs to make a UIwebview that can only scroll vertically(I need to disable to the horizontal scrolling), I can't really do it from the website because that's not in my control. How to implement that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable UIWebview horizontal scrolling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397699/how-to-disable-uiwebview-horizontal-scrolling)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding the following in the  section of your HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Do this either before you load the file into the web view or use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`